Flask/SQLAlchemy combining paginate() and union() results together returns only integers?
I have separate queries that I want to union and then paginate together. Based on the SQLAlchemy docs for Flask, paginate() and Pagination:

Call SQLAlchemy.paginate() on a select statement to get a Pagination object.

The following sort of works but I end up getting an error, because the paginate() on a union() fails to return Item objects, and is instead returning just a list of ints:

'int object' has no attribute 'id':

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

items_names = db.select(Item).filter(name=="eve")
items_property1 = db.select(Item).join(Item.properties1).filter(Property1.name=="eve")
items_property2 = db.select(Item).join(Item.properties2).filter(Property2.name=="eve")

results = db.paginate(db.union(items_names, items_property1, items_property2), per_page=50))

print(f"This is paginated page: {results.page}")
for item in results:
    print(item.id)     
    print(item.name)
    print("\n")

I think what's happening is it's only getting the ID column and nothing else:
# Example Run output:

items_names = [Item<1>, Item<3>]
items_property1 = [Item<1>, Item<2>]
items_property2 = [Item<4>]

results = [1,2,3,4]     # <-- This is what returns from db.paginate(), just Pagination object of integers
# ^^ But I expected Pagination of my Item objects, ie: Pagination([Item<1>, Item<2>, Item<3>, Item<4>])


"This is paginated page: 1"   # works fine 

>> Error occurs in for loop since I just get integers in results[]
for item in results:
    print(1.id)        # <-- of course can't get "id" from "int", program dies here
    print(1.name)
    print("\n")

How can I combine db.paginate() and db.union() to get a Pagination Object of Item results?
If it helps here are my Model definitions:
item_property1 = db.Table("item_property1",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property1_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property1.id"), primary_key=True)
)
item_property2 = db.Table("item_property2",
    Column("item_id", Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("property2_id", Integer, ForeignKey("property2.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Item(Model):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    # Many to Many
    properties1 = db.relationship('Property1', secondary=item_property1, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))
    properties2 = db.relationship('Property2', secondary=item_property2, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('items', lazy=True))


## Below Many-to-Many relationships
class Property1(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property1"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

class Property2(Model):
    __tablename__ = "property2"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

Any help really appreciated!

Generally you would do something like select(Item).from_statement(union_statement)) but paginate doesn't seem to like this. So your best bet is probably to devise  query that doesn't require union (bear in mind that SQLAlchemy should deduplicate the results in an ORM query anyway).
